# How does CONFIG FULL provide better handling capabilities in turbulent conditions?

Tags: landing, airbus-a320, turbulence, fctm

I wanted to get some clarity as to how does CONFIG FULL provide better handling capabilities in turbulent conditions?

This line mentioned in the A320 FCTM under the the supplementary procedures chapter
PR-NP-SP-10-10-3 P 3/4. But there is no explanation to it.

Could anyone help clarify. From what i can deduce this is from an aerodynamic aspect

Comment: I am not sure but CONFIG FULL reduces the stall speed and increases the lift which means that the aircraft can cope more easily with changes of wind speed/direction

Comment: Can you share the exact sentence in FCTM? I can't find it in my FCOM copy

Comment: @ocirocir that's because it isn't in the FCOM its in the FCTM. Kindly read the description of the question I have mentioned the exact reference.

Comment: @Jai Sorry I misspelled the last word, I mean that I can't find it in my FCTM copy.

Comment: @ocirocir the exact reference is attached in my question post. What's so difficult in finding it ? I presume you are aware of how to navigate to the specific chapter using the reference I have given.

Comment: @Jai There is nothing related to CONFIG FULL in my FCTM at that section, that's the point... You know there are different versions of FCTM, so providing a screenshot or copy and paste that line would be helpful to help you...

Comment: It's almost a certainty that this is not the case. Airplanes have better handling capability at lower flaps settings- why? because you're flying faster and therefore ailerons and rudders are more effective. But then again this is an Airbus.

Comment: @dashman that's the exact same thought which came to my mind when I read this line and it caused quite a bit of confusion.